# How do setup a npm / grunt development environment properly?

Tags: npm, package.json

I know that package.json has a `dependencies` section and a `devDependencies` section. I know package.json also has a `postinstall` hook. So I've currently got things setup like so:

- dependencies: everything the server needs to run
- devDependencies: everything I need to build the application (grunt and whatnot)
- postinstall: runs "grunt build"

The `grunt build` take all my source jade, stylus, and javascript files and compiles/minifies them into my html, css, and app.min.js files. All these go into a `./deploy` folder.

The `grunt build` process also copies in the server files (server.js and ./server/**/*) into the `./deploy` folder. The issue is how do I go about copying in only the correct `dependencies` from the `./node_modules/` folder into `./deploy/node_modules` and not all the `devDependencies` modules that aren't needed.

Is there something I can pass to `npm install` or put in `package.json` to tell it where to put the `dependencies`?

In the end I want to be able to zip up the `./deploy/` folder and send it off to a hosting site to run the app.